# JWTAuth is throwing error while logging out

Tags: laravel, jwt

being using JwtAuth in laravel for authentication. I have search all over the internet but nothing worked out.
Error while **Logging out**:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Tymon\JWTAuth\Manager::invalidate() must be an instance of Tymon\JWTAuth\Token, null given
```

Login and Register functions are working as required. The only issue is with this logout function. Not getting what's wrong?

Logout function:

```
public function logout(Request $request){
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ 
        'token' => 'required']);
 
    if ($validator->fails()) {             
        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()], 401);            
    }
    JWTAuth::invalidate($request->token);

    return response()->json([
        'status' => true,
        'message' => 'logout'
    ], 200);
}
```

Any insights?

Comment: $request->token : is empty maybe you have to put it in view

Comment: you may try instead of $request->token      JWTAuth::invalidate(JWTAuth::getToken()); Note: it means you must be under the jwt middleware to make sure that user is authenticated.

Comment: @Abdel-azizhassan Your solution isn't throwing up any error but it is also not removing auth_token from db

Comment: @DandyMandy, could you use the same token you invalidate to be authenticated? I am not sure but it's not recommended to store jwt tokens in db